# Draw rect with same Y coordinates

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I need draw candle stick chart. I draw candle via two triangles(for candle body) and line(fro shadow). Candle looks like this.

[image: candle]

Some times open and close price equals and all Y coordinates fro both triangles lie in one value. And  in this case OpenGl draw nothing fore these values. But i need draw small rect when this happens. May be exist some drawing mode what help me (now im  use GL_TRIANGLES) .Or another solution.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is an application logic issue, not a rendering issue. The application can detect the fact that the box is "too small" and should then adjust the vertex coordinates appropriately to define the minimum spacing.

Line primitives allow a line width to be specified (in pixels), so you could swap out triangles for lines for the "too small" cases, but I expect it's a little unwieldy and no easier than adjusting the triangle coordinates.

Comment: Im agree what its best solution for this case, but in my implementation a cant define minimum rect height, because this value depends on min an max price for all candles what contains in viewport.  And this value changes when user scroll chart view.
Im thought about new buffer what will hold these small candles and draw lines for them.But it seems like ugly solution.